# Tuple splat / apply in Rust

Tags: tuples, rust

I found [this discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/17274) about tuple splatting, but it is from 2014.

The example given is:

```
fn sum(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 {
    x + y
}

fn prepare_args () -> (i32, i32) {
    (1, 2)
}

fn main() {
    sum(prepare_args()); // Doesn't work
}
```

And the proposed solution is to roll your own `apply` function:

```
fn apply<A,B,C>(f: |A,B|->C, t: (A,B)) -> C {
    let (a,b) = t;
    f(a,b)
}

fn main() {
    apply(sum, prepare_args());
}
```

Is this currently the best way to go? If so, what is the correct syntax here? I get some errors including `expected type, found`|`at line 1 col 20` using the above.

Is there still no tuple splat operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a splat operator.

The code you found from 2014 is from before Rust 1.0, so it is outdated. To make the `apply` function work in post 1.0 Rust, change it into the following:

```
fn sum(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 {
    x + y
}

fn prepare_args() -> (i32, i32) {
    (1, 2)
}

fn apply<A, B, C, F>(f: F, t: (A, B)) -> C
    where F : Fn(A, B) -> C
{
    let (a, b) = t;
    f(a, b)
}

fn main() {
    let x = apply(sum, prepare_args());
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

This code compiles and runs correctly on [the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20sum%28x%3A%20i32%2C%20y%3A%20i32%29%20-%3E%20i32%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%2B%20y%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20prepare_args%28%29%20-%3E%20%28i32%2C%20i32%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%281%2C%202%29%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20apply%3CA%2C%20B%2C%20C%2C%20F%3E%28f%3A%20F%2C%20t%3A%20%28A%2C%20B%29%29%20-%3E%20C%0A%20%20%20%20where%20F%20%3A%20Fn%28A%2C%20B%29%20-%3E%20C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20%28a%2C%20b%29%20%3D%20t%3B%0A%20%20%20%20f%28a%2C%20b%29%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20apply%28sum%2C%20prepare_args%28%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20x%29%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0).

You could alternatively use `f(t.0, t.1)` as the body of `apply`, or destructure right there in the parameter list ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20sum%28x%3A%20i32%2C%20y%3A%20i32%29%20-%3E%20i32%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%2B%20y%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20prepare_args%28%29%20-%3E%20%28i32%2C%20i32%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%281%2C%202%29%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20apply%3CA%2C%20B%2C%20C%2C%20F%3E%28f%3A%20F%2C%20%28a%2C%20b%29%3A%20%28A%2C%20B%29%29%20-%3E%20C%0A%20%20%20%20where%20F%20%3A%20Fn%28A%2C%20B%29%20-%3E%20C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20f%28a%2C%20b%29%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20apply%28sum%2C%20prepare_args%28%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20x%29%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn apply<A, B, C, F>(f: F, (a, b): (A, B)) -> C
    where F : Fn(A, B) -> C
{
    f(a, b)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Proving a negative is always quite difficult...

As far as I know, there is indeed no tuple splat operator. However, the `Fn*` family of traits ([Fn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html)) takes a single argument, as a tuple.

On a nightly compiler, activating some unstable features, you can thus use:

```
#![feature(fn_traits)]
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

fn sum(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 {
    x + y
}

fn prepare_args () -> (i32, i32) {
    (1, 2)
}

fn main() {
    let func: &Fn(i32, i32) -> i32 = &sum;
    let result = func.call(prepare_args());
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Not too ideal, but then in the absence of support for variadics, you always need to know the number of elements of your tuple anyway so the value is low.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version of `apply` that works for tuples with sizes from 1 to 6 (can be increased) ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d1284ceed96866d42d413aa2964bbac5&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn main() {
    let add1 = |x| x + 1;
    let sum2 = ::std::ops::Add::add;
    let sum3 = |a, b, c| a + b + c;
    assert_eq!(apply(add1, (1,)), 2);
    assert_eq!(apply(sum2, (1, 2)), 3);
    assert_eq!(apply(sum3, (1, 2, 3)), 6);
}

#[inline(always)]
pub fn apply<Fun, In, Out>(fun: Fun, params: In) -> Out
    where ApplyImpl: Apply<Fun, In, Out>
{
    ApplyImpl::apply(fun, params)
}

pub trait Apply<Fun, In, Out> {
    fn apply(fun: Fun, params: In) -> Out;
}

pub struct ApplyImpl;

macro_rules! impl_apply {
    () => ();
    ($A:ident, $($B:ident,)*) => (
        impl_apply!{$($B,)*}

        impl<$A, $($B,)* Fun, Out> Apply<Fun, ($A, $($B),*), Out> for ApplyImpl
        where Fun: Fn($A, $($B),*) -> Out
        {
            #[allow(non_snake_case)]
            #[inline(always)]
            fn apply(fun: Fun, params: ($A, $($B),*)) -> Out {
                // use type parameters as var names...
                let ($A, $($B),*) = params;
                fun($A, $($B),*)
            }
        }
    )
}

impl_apply!{A, B, C, D, E, F,}
```

---

I'm thinking in create a crate for it. If I do, I will put the link here.